# Xamarin Forms: ModernHttpClient errorhandling in PCL

Tags: exception, xamarin.forms

My app connects to an api which requires an HTTPS-connection.
ModernHttpClients (NativeMessageHandler) works fine until an exception is thrown...
When there is no wifi available, an UnknownHostException is thrown on Android. Is it possible to make a catch that works on both Android and iOS? UnknownHostException is in the Java.Net library which can't be used in the iOS project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ConnectivityPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin) in your shared Xamarin Forms code to check for an internet connection before doing your request.

Comment: Not really a great solution considering all the other errors that may be thrown, for instance when there is in fact a mobile connection but it's flaky. The fact that there's a connection when you start doing your stuff is absolutely no guarantee that it'll stay there while your doing your stuff.

Comment: Absolutely true, but the same component also exposes events that handle when the connectivity changed so you can hook in to those to handle situations like the one you're describing.

Comment: That's hardly useful if your connection drops while you're performing a request. I'm not saying that you shouldn't check for connection - you should, and it prevents a lot of problems. I'm just saying that this doesn't at all rid you of the need to perform connection exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'm using a cross platform interface to handle network errors. You can for instance have something like (using MvvmCross in this example):

```
try
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var result = await client.GetAsync("http://some-url.com");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    var platformErrorChecker = Mvx.Resolve<IPlatformNetworkError>();
    if (platformErrorChecker.IsNetworkError(e))
    {
        // Handle network error
    }
    else
    {
        // Other exception, just throw
        throw;
    }
}
```

And a service defined as:

```
public interface IPlatformNetworkError
{
    bool IsNetworkError(Exception e);
}
```

Which you implement on each platform specifically, or only where needed. This is a simple example of course, you can have each platform provide more information about their specific network errors.